# How do I change the ProgressDialog loader(spinner)?

Tags: android

Need to change the color spinner of the default Progress Dialog on the API 21 and above.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setProgress(R.id.progressBar);
    progressDialog.setMessage(message);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(R.style.MaterialTheme);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
```

And my material theme is

```
<!-- Material theme. -->
<style name="MaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

</style>

<style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: please post some code here

Answer (score 0):

You save this xml as a file and put it in the drawable folder ( let's 
say   my_progress.xml ) than you set it as a drawable in
**MyProgressBar.setProgressDrawable()**
To change colors - you'll need to change those values in @color/progress_start
**@color/progress_end** It's basically a gradient and you
can put hex in there.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item android:id="@android:id/background">
<shape>
    <corners android:radius="5dip" />
    <gradient
            android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
            android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
            android:centerY="0.75"
            android:endColor="#ff747674"
            android:angle="270"
    />
</shape>
</item>

 <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
<clip>
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</clip>
 </item>

  <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
  <clip>
    <shape>
        <corners
            android:radius="5dip" />
         <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/progress_start"
            android:endColor="@color/progress_end"
            android:angle="270" 
          />
     </shape>
   </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```